# Retrieve data from iPhone 5 after activating new phone

Tags: iphone, ios

I recently purchased an iPhone 6.  I neglected to remove data from my iPhone 5 before activating my new phone.  Now it seems impossible to remove data from my old iPhone 5 as it is not active or connected to anything!

Comment: If it says "insert SIM" then just move your SIM back from the new phone briefly.  turn off findmyiphone, clear the memory and move your SIM back.

Answer (score 1):

Make a backup of your old iPhone to iCloud, if you have wifi available, or iTunes, connecting your iPhone with a cable to your computer.
Then reset your new iPhone —provided there is no new information or data because resetting it will erase everything— and when asked choose    "Restore from iCloud Backup" or "Restore from iTunes Backup", depending on the case. Chose the latest backup available, and you're set.

More detailed steps can be found here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201269

Answer (score 0):

Use iTunes to restore your phone the factory defaults no internet needed and you'll it will completely wipe your phone